# Can't find spock inside of intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, spock

I am pretty new to intellij and spock.

I am adding spock testing to my spring boot project using gradle. Here's my `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.4.0.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

jar {
    baseName = 'theta-server'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile('org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.4')
}


eclipse {
    classpath {
         containers.remove('org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER')
         containers 'org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8'
    }
}
```

And so I added a spock test such:

```
package com.heavyweightsoftware.theta.server.controller

/**
 * 
 */
class ThetaControllerTest extends spock.lang.Specification {
    def "Theta"() {

    }
}
```

But I can't run the test inside my intellij environment because it says "cannot resolve symbol 'spock'"

The build runs fine directly.

Comment: Adding the dependency worked flawlessly for me. Did you already try the "Refresh all gradle projects" button from the gradle tool-window?

Comment: If you don't see a Gradle Tool Window, close and re-open the project.  When you open it, use the build.gradle file to let IntelliJ know that it is a Gradle project (it will ask if you want to re-import; say "yes").

Comment: @Morfic "Refresh all radle projects" did the trick. Thanks, I couldn't find this on the web anywhere. Will you post as an answer so I can accept?

Comment: No problem. Most of the time IJ syncs changes, but I had this happening to me using maven a few times and this is usually what gets it working again. Only a couple of times I had to force a cache invalidation because anything else was failing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At times, IJ may not update the project classpath after some changes. It seems that this happens for both `Maven POM files` as well as `Gradle build files`. Usually, this is easily solved by forcing a sync with the `Reimport all gradle/maven projects` button from the appropriate tool window ([maven](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/maven-projects-tool-window.html), [gradle](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/synchronizing-changes-in-gradle-project-and-intellij-idea-project.html)):

[image: Gradle]

[image: Maven]